# Using TimeMachine backups after changing (short) username on OS X?

Tags: macos, time-machine, user-account

I changed my (short) username on OS X Mountain Lion using the instructions mentioned [here](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3872).

I am guessing that would sort of invalidate all the TimeMachine backups I had till now. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Did you change the user id?

Comment: Is that different from the short username?

Comment: If you open your backup via TM and go back in time, do you see both your old name in `/Users`?

Comment: @HimanshuPokhariya - no - in terminal as the user type id and look at the value of uid

Comment: @patrix: I renamed the old user folder to the new one (as part of the the username changing process). So the backups before the change have the old username and the one's after have the new one.

Comment: @Mark: I typed 'id' on the terminal. The username part of the uid has changed, of course. I don't know if the numeric value has changed as well, because I don't know what it was previously.

Answer (score 1):

The `tmutil inheritbackup` command in Terminal will let you inherit a backup from a different disk or computer. However, I doubt that it will inherit files from a different user account. In other words, it might give you access to the backup, but not to the files in the account with a different name. It's worth trying though.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising indeed. I am new to the Mac (and its command line). Do you think you can provide more pointers on how/if it would be possible to inherit backups from the renamed user folder.

Comment: The tmutil command is complex. Type man tmutil in Terminal to see how it works. There are some examples that should help you.

Comment: `inheritbackup` works on machine/system level, not on user level. So I don't see how this can help here.